# AS3 Tracing a Class extended from the Event Class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have created a class (extends the Event class) for use in one of my projects. 
If I trace the custom event object in the called function I get 'Event' as the type, but if I trace a TimerEvent, or MouseEvent, etc, I get TimerEvent or MouseEvent...
Let me demonstrate:

```
var c:CustomObject = new CustomObject();
c.addEventListener(CustomEvent.ON_SEND_MESSAGE,fnc);

function fnc(e:CustomEvent) {
    trace(e);
}
```

This traces:

```
[Event type="onSendMessage" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
```

While this code:

```
var f:Timer = new Timer(2000);
f.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,th);
f.start();

function th(e:TimerEvent):void {
    trace(e);
}
```

traces this:

```
[TimerEvent type="timer" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
```

Why does my custom event class not trace [CustomEvent ...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the toString() method:

```
public override function toString(): String
{
   return "[CustomEvent]";
}
```

Disclaimer: Haven't used flash/flex in a while. But I think that is correct.